# Why does the moon looks like having different filters sometimes?

Tags: the-moon

Why does the moon look more yellow or more LED-like?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by more yellow or more LED-like? More yellow compared to what?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: because of the Earth's atmosphere.

When the Moon is low on the horizon, the light we receive from the Moon has to go through a lot of layers of the atmosphere. [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) makes this light more yellowish/orangish, for the same reason sunsets look orange.

A very thin layer of clouds can also change the appearance of the Moon.

Sometimes, the Moon ends up [in the Earth's shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_eclipse). In this case, the light that hits the Moon first went through the Earth's atmosphere. Because of Rayleigh scattering (again), the light that went through the atmosphere is red. This gives the Moon a reddish tint.